# Entity Framework and SQL Server Compact Edition DDEX Provider

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I try to use Entity Framework with a SQL Server Compact Edition database file, but when I try to update all models in VS, this message appears:

[image]

Can you help me please?

Comment: ok TT, thx for ur suggestion, the next post i will have it present, i add the error at english and u give me a point XD

Answer (score 1):

You can install "EF Core Power Tools", they include a simple DDEX provider for SQL Server Compact 4.0

Comment: Hello Erik , thx for answer but now have another problem, i installed EF Core Power Tools but appear this: http://programandonet.com/images/75799/zlPDm.png

"Your Project reference the latest version of entity Framework; an entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data Connection. if you have already installed a compatible provider , ensure you have rebuild your project before prforming this action. otherwise, exit this wizard, install a compatible provider and rebuild your project before performing this action."